# jQuery - Smooth scroll code not working

Tags: jquery, html, scroll

So, I was making a webpage and wanted to include some smooth scroll in it using jQuery. The problem is that my code isn't working and when I click on the link the page directly jumps to the spot instead of scrolling smoothly. Here's the relevat part of the code -

HTML -

```
<script src="scroll.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="sec1">
    <span id="header">Heading</span>
    <!--<span id="notheader">Umesh meena is the coolest</span>-->
    <!--<div id="navbar" class="before">lol</div>-->
    <a href="#sec2" id="button1" >link to the page</a>
</div>
<div id="sec2">
    <span id="main">lorem</span>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

SCROLL.js file -

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('a[href^="#"]').on('click',function (e) {
      e.preventDefault();

      var target = this.hash;
      var $target = $(target);

      $('html, body').stop().animate({
          'scrollTop': $target.offset().top
      }, 900, 'swing', function () {
          window.location.hash = target;
      });
  });
});
```

apart from this I do have another javascript file linked ( which I shouldnt think should interfere with the smooth-scroll code. Please help/ suggest options.

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('a[href^="#"]').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var target = this.hash;
    var $target = $(target);

    if ($target.length === 0) {
      alert('No target!');
      return;
    }
    
    $('html, body').animate({
      scrollTop: $target.offset().top
    }, 900, 'swing', function() {
      window.location.hash = target;
    });
  });
});
```

```css
div[id*="sec"] {
  margin-bottom: 500px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="sec1">
  <span id="header">Heading</span>
  <!--<span id="notheader">Umesh meena is the coolest</span>-->
  <!--<div id="navbar" class="before">lol</div>-->
  <a href="#sec2" id="button1">link to the page</a>
  <a href="#sec3" id="button2">link to the page</a>
  <a href="#sec4" id="button3">link to no target</a>
</div>
<div id="sec2">
  <span id="main">lorem</span>
</div>
<div id="sec3">
  <span id="main">ipsum</span>
</div>
<div id="notarget">
  <span id="main">Vous aved un chat.</span>
</div>
```